# Struggling to append the data from all the pages using loop when extracting data from paginated API in python?

Tags: python, api, pagination

I'm trying to pull out the data from API however I'm facing a  hard moment to append the data from all the pages. I got just the last page.

Not sure what doesn't work in code below.
I tried as well with adding `.json()` to `requests.get` part but then the code doesn't work at all.
Not sure if its important but there are 87666 records which I need to fetch so I tried to pull out 88 pages with 1000 records each.
How I should provide correctly API token and password to auth function ?

```
username = "xxx"
password= "xxx"
    
all_pages = []

for page in range(1,88):
      url = 'https://api.riskmethods.net/v1/indicator_messages?per_page=1000 page='+str(page)
      data = requests.get(url=url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username','password'))
      all_pages.append(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try as below

```
username = "xxx"
password= "xxx"
    
all_pages = []
    
for page in range(1,88):
    url = 'https://api.riskmethods.net/v1/indicator_messages?per_page=1000 page='+str(page)
    resp = requests.get(url=url,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username','password'))
    data = json.loads(resp.text) ## If response in json
    data = resp.text ## else      
    all_pages.append(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response Anil however for me it doesn't work . I got an error: "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"